# Can the Beast attack from a distance?

Tags: specter-ops

The rules state

> the Beast can move 5 spaces on a turn, but can attack the Agent only
>   if it shares the same space that turn

I believe this means that the beast can only attack the Agent it shares a space with if it moved 5 spaces that particular turn. However...

**If the Beast moves less than 5 spaces, does it attack from a distance like normal?**

Answer (score 2):

In a [boardgamegeek thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1356692/beast-and-prophet-clarifications), the designer clarified that if the Beast moves LESS than 5 spaces, he can still attack from a distance.